# UIscrollview not working ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

[image]

I tried to implement thorugh this method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
        super.viewDidLoad()
mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 530);
          // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

but then also scrollbar not working properly.

Comment: "not working" is not a sufficient description to get any useful help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your mistake is you should not give content size.
And for automatic scrolling you can do auto-layout constraint.

Answer (score 2):

self.scrollView.contentSize = self.scrollView.superview!.bounds.size

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you have set scrollview(0,0,600,600)
2. Setting the autolayout for scrollview leading,trailing,top,bottom.
3. Second, you have set contentview inside your scrollview(0,0,600,600)
4. Setting the autolayout for contentview like leading,trailing,top,bottom.
5. Third, Setting contentview width is Equal to superview width.
6. Fourth, Setting contentview height.
7. It's working perfectly.

Comment: As we cannot have any idea what "not working" means, all this is just some random guessing. And most of it is probably completely unrelated to the problem.